# Dojo creating DOM nodes dynamically

Tags: dom, dojo

I'm trying to create a custom Dojo widget for my application.

```
<!-- Dojo widget Template  -->
<div class="newsHomeWidget">
    <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <tbody dojoAttachPoint="newsHomeTableTbody">
            <!-- May be we need to repeat this code dynamically -->
            <tr>
                <td class="ncmseparate">
                    <a class="wordwrap" dojoAttachPoint="newsHomeLink"></a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

This widget is to display the list of News that I get from my service.I will get the Data in `JSON` format. I need to display the News Text in the anchor tag whose class is `wordWrap` and the link to the news as the `href` of this anchor tag.

Since there can be multiple news, I need to repeat  for each News. I would like to do this in the best way. I can manually create the DOM for each value of News using dojo.create or `dojo.place`.But that requires lot of hard coding. Could you please suggest me the best way to do this? Is it possible to do that in the Widget template itself?

Comment: Which version of Dojo are you on? (1.7 has some major differences from its predecessors.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way would be to create a private templated widget that represents an individual news item.

for example

```
dojo.declare('NewsItem',[dijit._Widget,dijit._Templated],{
  url:'',
  headline:'',
  //template abbreviated
  templateString:'<tr><td><a href="${url}>${headline}</a></td></tr>'
});
```

Then when you retrieve the list of news from your data service, you can just iterate over each element of that array and create a new NewsItem widget and place it in the your tbody, `this.newsHomeTableTbody`.

```
var newsArray = [...]
dojo.forEach(newsArray, function(newsLink){
  var newsItem = new NewsItem({
    url: newsLink.url,
    headline: newsLink.headline
  });
  newsItem.placeAt(this.newsHomeTableTbody);

},this);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. One question. In the below code "newsItem.placeAt(this.newsHomeTableTbody);" "this" will be the global scope right? So if that is the case how can I get access to newsHomeTablyTbody?

Comment: the dojo.forEach function takes an array, a function, and an optional third parameter of scope.  I was under the impression this code would be executing inside your custom templated widget, therefore I used `this` as the third parameter of the dojo.forEach function call.  You could just as easily pass in an instance of your custom widget if you are creating `NewsItems` somewhere else: `dojo.forEach(newsArray,newItemCreationFunction, instanceOfNewsHomeWidget);`

Comment: I'm able to construct this widget. Thanks for your help. But in my cod this is what I'm doing.   `<table>
   <tbody id="newsContentTable">
   </tbody>
  </table>` and the dynamic elements are inserted into "newsContentTable". But is this a complete widget? I need to have the above structure for this widget to work? How can I improve it?

Comment: Design-wise, the `NewsItem` widget class is tightly coupled with the general `News` widget.  Without knowing the greater view of things it's tough to say how to improve it.

Comment: OK. I understand, may be changing the strucuture should help me right?, i.e; using DIVs instead of tables.